# HTML headers not showing up next to each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show two headings and they aren't showing up.
I tested both individually and they work but combined it doesn't work.

```
$("html").html("<h1 style='position:absolute;left:20%;color:green;'>test1</h1>"); // load1

$("html").html("<h2 style='position:absolute;left:60%;color:green;'>test2</h2>"); // load2
```

Comment: In an HTML document, all content must go in `<body>` which is a direct child of `<html>`. You should be using `$("body")` instead of `$("html")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you overwrite the first header by using `html()` the second time. Use `append()` in the second case:

```js
$("html").html("<h1 style='position:absolute;left:20%;color:green;'>test1</h1>"); 
$("html").append("<h2 style='position:absolute;left:60%;color:green;'>test2</h2>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or add the new header to the old html:

```js
$("html").html("<h1 style='position:absolute;left:20%;color:green;'>test1</h1>"); 
$("html").html($("html").html()+"<h2 style='position:absolute;left:60%;color:green;'>test2</h2>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/html/

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content.

You're overwriting the first heading with the second. Try `append()` instead, which adds to the element. In vanilla JS, you would do `innerHTML += "more html here";`.

On another note, use of `innerHTML` (vanilla JS) or `.html()` (jQuery) is not encouraged.